# Checked out previous git commit, now can't switch back to HEAD

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, git-checkout, git-stash

In my React Native project I checked out a previous git commit using `git checkout <previous commit SHA>`, then tried to return to HEAD using `git checkout <most recent commit SHA>`. It said `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: android/gradlew.bat. Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.`
I did `git stash` and then `git checkout <most recent commit SHA>` again, but it gave me the same `Your local changes` error.

How can I get back to HEAD?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do want to keep your changes (otherwise just `git reset --hard HEAD`), you could switch to a new branch (`git switch -c [new name here]`), commit the changes there, then head back to your `main` and perform a hard reset to `HEAD` as mentioned above. I'm not sure why the stashing isn't working for you, but this should save your changes in the new branch, bring you back to `HEAD` in `main`, and allow you to then merge in your branch with the changes however you see fit (a rebase might be in order).